# Why is $(1-t)^2 == (t-1)^2$ in SageMath?

Tags: sagemath

This is really odd, not much to say about it.

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 8.5, Release Date: 2018-12-22                     │
│ Using Python 2.7.15. Type "help()" for help.                       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[image: -t]

Comment: Are you sure this question wouldn't be better answered in another SE?

Comment: @AniruddhVenkatesan Where would you recommend?

Comment: That depends on what type of answer you're looking for. If you're looking for a reason as to why Python respond and return this result, Stack Overflow might be a better choice. If you want a mathematical explanation, then I would suggest leaving the question on this site and trying to see if someone knows the answer

Comment: What is "*odd*" about this?  Do you have reason to doubt the result?  What result did you expect and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic algebra, namely laws of exponents:

$(t-1)^2 = (-1(1-t))^2= (-1)^2(1-t)^2 = (1-t)^2$

Comment: should have paid attention in elementary school

Comment: To **really** see it, let $t=3$.  This says $2^2= (-2)^2$.  Well, yeah.

Comment: @LouisHong You don't learn this in elementary, you learn this in algebra, guess you didn't pay attention in there either haha

Answer (score 1):

Forget $1-t$. Instead, think $T$. Is it so surprising/odd  that $$(T)^2 = (-T)^2$$
?

Alternatively we can expand them:

$$(1-t)(1-t)=(1)(1) +(2)(1)(-t)+(-t)(-t)=1-2t+t^2$$

$$(t-1)(t-1)=(t)(t)+2(-1)(t)+(-1)(-1)=t^2-2t+1$$